# mod_security в apache2 на ubuntu 14.04.4 x64

Tags: apache2

**Всем доброго времени.**

Пожалуйста, помогите с настройкой модуля mod_security в apache2 на ubuntu 14.04.4 x64, нашел кучу ссылок и статей по этому поводу, но все либо 2012-2015 годов, либо совсем не точная информация... А именно, к примеру у меня ставится libapache2_modsecurity2, соответственно ставится ни mod_security, а модуль: secutiry2, отсюда многие конфиги не работают... Но это еще пол беды. Все же удалось настроить модуль, но в итоге при использовании OWASP ModSecurity правил, получаю кучу ошибок о блокировке всего и вся. Использовал как base_rules, так и active_rules. В общем нужен нормальный мануал, если кто то может написать или дать нормальную ссылку как полностью настроить этот модуль, с разъяснениями и примерами? Заранее очень благодарен.

Конкретно результаты моей установки (включенные опции):
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf:

```
SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity
IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/*.conf
Include /etc/modsecurity/base_rules/*.conf
```

Файл /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.load:

```
LoadFile /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
LoadModule security2_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so
```

Файл /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf:

```
#SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
SecRuleEngine On
SecServerSignature FreeOSHTTP
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" \
     "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"
#SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200
SecRequestBodyLimit 16384000
#SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 16384000
#SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 16384000
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject
SecRule REQBODY_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200001', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2"
SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200002',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:44, \
msg:'Multipart request body failed strict validation: \
PE %{REQBODY_PROCESSOR_ERROR}, \
BQ %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED}, \
BW %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_WHITESPACE}, \
DB %{MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE}, \
DA %{MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER}, \
HF %{MULTIPART_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
LF %{MULTIPART_LF_LINE}, \
SM %{MULTIPART_MISSING_SEMICOLON}, \
IQ %{MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING}, \
IP %{MULTIPART_INVALID_PART}, \
IH %{MULTIPART_INVALID_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
FL %{MULTIPART_FILE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED}'"
SecRule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200003',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,msg:'Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary.'"
SecPcreMatchLimit 1000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 1000
SecRule TX:/^MSC_/ "!@streq 0" \
        "id:'200004',phase:2,t:none,deny,msg:'ModSecurity internal error flagged: %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}'"
SecResponseBodyAccess On
SecResponseBodyMimeType text/plain text/html text/xml
SecResponseBodyLimit 524288
SecResponseBodyLimitAction ProcessPartial
SecTmpDir /tmp/
SecDataDir /tmp/
SecAuditLogParts ABIJDEFHZ
SecAuditLogType Serial
SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
SecArgumentSeparator &
SecCookieFormat 0
SecUnicodeMapFile unicode.mapping 20127
```

Файл /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf: стандартный из OWASP

Файл /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers            5
    MinSpareServers     5
    MaxSpareServers     10
    MaxRequestWorkers       200
    ServerLimit         200
    MaxClients              200
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  2000
    MaxRequestsPerChild     2000
</IfModule>
```

Соответственно в папке /etc/modsecurity 2 файла *.conf: modsecurity.conf и modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf

**ВОПРОС 1:** стоит ли грузить оба конфиг файла или достаточно modsecurity.conf, что значит: modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf это сетап файл настройки или он должен работать всегда?

**ВОПРОС 2:** Какие правила точно будут работать и какие использовать base_rules или activated_rules?

**ВОПРОС 3:** В файле /etc/apache2/apache2.conf есть настройка, скрыть информацию об Апаче, конкретно ServerTokens Prod, но при этой настройке при запуске mod_security ругается на то что длина токена не полная, включите полную длину токена, соответственно:  ServerTokens Full, но отсюда Апач будет показывать информацию о себе, что мне не нужно, как с этим жить?

**ВОПРОС 4:** В файле /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.load запись для загрузки LoadFile libxml2.so.2 оставить так или прописать полностью LoadFile /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2?

**ВОПРОС 5:** Как найти информацию о версии mod_security, а также о базе правил OWASP? Вопрос совместимости версий, чтобы небыло как в одной из статей что версия OWASP правила не подходят по версию mod_security? (я ставил все с репозитория по ману).

**ВОПРОС 6: Собственно логи, при начальной загрузке Апача, получаем в файле /etc/apache2 error.log:

```
Mon Aug 08 18:06:25.000070 2016] [:notice] [pid 4771] ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 () configured.
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:25.000169 2016] [:notice] [pid 4771] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.1-dev"; loaded version="1.5.1-dev"
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:25.000176 2016] [:notice] [pid 4771] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.31 "; loaded version="8.31 2012-07-06"
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:25.000181 2016] [:notice] [pid 4771] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:25.000185 2016] [:notice] [pid 4771] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:26.006486 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4772] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 08 18:06:26.006590 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4772] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Что можно сказать по этому начальному логу? Все ли правильно или что то не загружено, по крайней мере модуля: evasive не нашел, хотя ставил параллельно.

**ВОПРОС 7:** Собственно ошибки при работе mod_security, просто при получении доступа к одному из сайтов (перенаправляется в папку сайта файлом .htaccess):

```
[Mon Aug 08 18:11:15.017274 2016] [:error] [pid 4777] [client 192.168.0.100] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "\\\\W{4,}" at ARGS:code. [file "/etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf"] [line "37"] [id "960024"] [rev "2"] [msg "Meta-Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Repetative Non-Word Characters"] [data "Matched Data: \\xd3\\xea\\xe0\\xe6\\xe8\\xf2\\xe5 \\xe0\\xe4\\xf0\\xe5\\xf1 \\xfd\\xeb. \\xef\\xee\\xf7\\xf2\\xfb \\xef\\xee\\xeb\\xf3\\xf7\\xe0\\xf2\\xe5\\xeb\\xff? found within ARGS:code: \\xd3\\xea\\xe0\\xe6\\xe8\\xf2\\xe5 \\xe0\\xe4\\xf0\\xe5\\xf1 \\xfd\\xeb. \\xef\\xee\\xf7\\xf2\\xfb \\xef\\xee\\xeb\\xf3\\xf7\\xe0\\xf2\\xe5\\xeb\\xff?"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [hostname "site.com"] [uri "/upload.php"] [unique_id "V6ho0sCoAOgAABKpzNoAAAAB"]
[Mon Aug 08 18:11:15.027209 2016] [:error] [pid 4777] [client 192.168.0.100] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator LT matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "33"] [id "981203"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score (Total Inbound Score: 3, SQLi=0, XSS=0): Meta-Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Repetative Non-Word Characters"] [hostname "site.com"] [uri "/box/upload.php"] [unique_id "V6ho0sCoAOgAABKpzNoAAAAB"]
```

Файл modsec_audit.log получает вот такой лог:

```
--3694d703-A--
[08/Aug/2016:18:11:15 +0700] V6ho0sCoAOgAABKpzNoAAAAB 192.168.0.100 56540 192.168.0.230 80
--3694d703-B--
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 315
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://site.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 YaBrowser/16.7.0.3342 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBQhab1BHnSIbcaqP
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: http://site.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utmz=61650367.1465064573.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=61650367.977473803.1465064573.1465179927.1465184383.3; PHPSESSID=qq0nj7d06rhu2um6tgonsa6ha0

--3694d703-I--
code=%d3%ea%e0%e6%e8%f2%e5+%e0%e4%f0%e5%f1+%fd%eb%2e+%ef%ee%f7%f2%fb+%ef%ee%eb%f3%f7%e0%f2%e5%eb%ff%3f
--3694d703-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1228
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

--3694d703-H--
Message: Warning. Pattern match "\\W{4,}" at ARGS:code. [file "/etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf"] [line "37"] [id "960024"] [rev "2"] [msg "Meta-Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Repetative Non-Word Characters"] [data "Matched Data: \xd3\xea\xe0\xe6\xe8\xf2\xe5 \xe0\xe4\xf0\xe5\xf1 \xfd\xeb. \xef\xee\xf7\xf2\xfb \xef\xee\xeb\xf3\xf7\xe0\xf2\xe5\xeb\xff? found within ARGS:code: \xd3\xea\xe0\xe6\xe8\xf2\xe5 \xe0\xe4\xf0\xe5\xf1 \xfd\xeb. \xef\xee\xf7\xf2\xfb \xef\xee\xeb\xf3\xf7\xe0\xf2\xe5\xeb\xff?"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"]
Message: Warning. Operator LT matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "33"] [id "981203"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score (Total Inbound Score: 3, SQLi=0, XSS=0): Meta-Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Repetative Non-Word Characters"]
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1470654674970974 56402 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1470654674970974 56402; combined=3072, p1=463, p2=2500, p3=0, p4=0, p5=109, sr=100, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9.
Server: Apache
Engine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"

--3694d703-J--
2,0,"","<Unknown ContentType>"
Total,0

--3694d703-Z--
```

**ВОПРОС 8:** Как сделать чтобы лог писался по человечески? А не:

```
\\xd3\\xea\\xe0\\xe6\\xe8\\xf2\\xe5 \\xe0\\xe4\\xf0\\xe5\\xf1 \\xfd\\xeb. \\xef\\xee\\xf7\\xf2\\xfb \\xef\\xee\\xeb\\xf3\\xf7\\xe0\\xf2\\xe5\\xeb\\xff? found within ARGS:code: \\xd3\\xea\\xe0\\xe6\\xe8\\xf2\\xe5 \\xe0\\xe4\\xf0
```

**ВОПРОС 9:** Собственно главные проблемы и лог /etc/apache2/error.log думал что это из-за .htaccess и mod_rewrite, но выключив .htaccess все тоже самое:

```
"([\\\\~\\\\!\\\\@\\\\#\\\\$\\\\%\\\\^\\\\&\\\\*\\\\(\\\\)\\\\-\\\\+\\\\=\\\\{\\\\}\\\\[\\\\]\\\\|\\\\:\\\\;\\"\\\\'\\\\\\xc2\\xb4\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x99\\\\\\xe2\\x80\\x98\\\\`\\\\<\\\\>].*?){8,}" at REQUEST_COOKIES:feedTreeSaveStateCookie. [file "/etc/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "157"] [id "981172"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"] [data "Matched Data: - found within REQUEST_COOKIES:feedTreeSaveStateCookie: root,root/CAT:-1,root/CAT:-1/FEED:-3,root/CAT:-1/FEED:-1,root/CAT:-1/FEED:-4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [hostname "sub.site.com"] [uri "/backend.php"] [unique_id "V6hrisCoAOgAABOCD3UAAAAA"]
```

Заранее спасибо! За все подсказки и советы!

з.ы. В основе использовал этот ман: thefanclub co za/how-to/how-install-apache2-modsecurity-and-modevasive-ubuntu-1204-lts-server

---

Сколько бы не бадался с mod security, толку нет, последняя попытка, все снес и заново поставил, заново настроил, фильтрация работает, удалил все правила в .htaccess, все сделал чистенько, настроил виртуальные хосты в Апаче, все по фен шую... Все равно НЕ РАБОТАЕТ! К примеру сайт из Яндекс браузера рубит, а из IE и FF, нет ) просто непонятно, как работают правила... Использую последнюю версию и mod security и OWASP баз правил, включаю только базовые и опциональные. Даже при опции в apache2.conf:

    
    SecRuleEngine Off

Приходится вырубать все:
    
    SecRuleEngine Off

Не помогает! Site.ru все равно, где открывается, где то нет, главная к примеру откроется в IE, затем по ссылке на сайте проходишь = 403, mod security рубит нещадно!

У меня вопрос, на кой ляд такие првила, где самый простой сайт на html рубит за здрасти? Есть хоть кто то, кто может помочь по теме правил и работы mod security?

Comment: Вопрос 6 - да, всё нормально. Мелкий нотис AH00094 не в счёт.

Comment: Да вроде то да ) но почему так сильно рубит все и вся? И как сделать логи из 16ки в хотябы UTF-8, директива UTF-8 конвертации, включена в /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf но толку от нее 0?

Comment: здесь принято задавать *конкретные* вопросы, а у вас же здесь аж **9** вопросов

Comment: Почему шестой вопрос не в **болде**?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Это альбинос

Comment: Разбейте на отдельные вопросы. Потому что если будет один ответ на вопросы 1, 3, 5, а другой — на 1, 4 и 9, то какой из них вы примете как правильный?